# how to avoid a starting activity when it's called

Tags: android, android-activity

I'll try to explain it, I have two Activities, I'd create an activity with a button. When the button is pressed I don't want to the second activity starts, how can i do that? if you need some code tell me please!!

Comment: can u plz brief your question???

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your problem, do you want to start a new `activity` and close the current one that is open?

Comment: please write detail of question with code?

Comment: Is it that, when you click a button, you don't want an activity to start? Then, don't start that activity on button click. It would help if you could explain the situation and the problem.

Comment: Just want to clarify. You have a activity with a button. When that button is pressed, you want to avoid a activity to be opened even if you call `startActivity` method of it. Is it?

Comment: ok, on the first activity i have three text fields, and i put on the code a conditional that says when three text fields isn't filled, don't open the second activity until the three fields are filled with the info @NareshR

Comment: then don't call the activity...

Comment: Have you tried an `if....else` condition? You know, if the 3 text fields are not filled, show a toast or something asking the user to fill em up. Else, open the activity. Posting the code should bring a lot of clarity to your question.

Comment: exactly! don't open the second activity until the three fields have the info @NareshR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
if(yourtextfield1.getText().toString().length>0&&yourtextfield2.getText().toString().length>0&&yourtextfield3.getText().toString().length>0){

   //start your second activity here
}else {
   // give a warning to user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You first make that button disabled `enable=false`.

Have a code like

```
private void validateButton()
{
    if(isAllDataEntered())
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_submit)).setEnabled(true);
}
```

Then you put something like this for all the editBoxes.

```
editUserName.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
```

and implement the methods and call it in `onTextChanged` method and You call this `validateButton` method.

In `isAllDataEntered` method, you can check if the Texts are entered.

Answer (score 0):

Put a check Like.

```
EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewbyId(r.id.edittext1);
EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewbyId(r.id.edittext2);
EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewbyId(r.id.edittext3);

if(!(et1.getText().equals("") &&et2.getText().equals("") &&et3.getText().equals(""))){
   StartActivity();
}
else
{
alertUser();
}
```

where edittext1,edittext2,edittext3 is ur editext in xml

Answer (score 0):

Set the launchMode of the activity in menifest to singleTop

```
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```